# Datasheet view edit list items not validating multiple users edition (SPOnline)

Tags: sharepoint-online, datasheet

so we have a list that a lot of users edit at the same time in list view edit mode (datasheet view),

if we were editing rows things at the same time we expected the red error telling us that one row wasn't able to be updated(this is what we expected)

now, turns out that if two users are modifying the same row at the same time,(even the same field) whoever is the last to submit the change, it will be  applied and sharepoint will not error out overriding the previous user changes.

Did something change ? shouldn't sharepoint error out if two users were modifying the same row at the same time ? is there a way to lock my item ?

this works in infopath but the user wants to be able to perform this changes on the datasheet view edit mode. like a checkout for list items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the OOB datasheet view dose not support it. And Check in/out feature only works in library instead of list.

In the item edit form with classic experience, user will get error message when the same item is edited by multiple users at the same time.

[image]

Other situations, such as edit item with modern experience, use datasheet view to edit item, the error will not show up. Multiple users can edit item at the same item without error. But only the last change will be saved and it will override whatever was entered into the item before it.

You can enable Versions. Check the version history for the item to see all changes users made before.